# VBA use filedialog to search, then copy and paste

Tags: vba, search, filedialog

Right now my code copies & pastes all of the data without any specific selection criteria. I'm trying to copy and paste specific information from certain files based upon their name into the active worksheet. I believe there is some function that I need that can help me with this. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set wbb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh = wbb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With fd
    .Title = "Please select Job Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    Err.Clear
    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If MsgBox("Files selected, continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        file = fd.SelectedItems(i)
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=file, ReadOnly:=True
        If file = "" Then Exit Sub
        filesheet = "Sheet1"
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(filesheet).Range("A1:A3").Copy
        LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Next i
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: pseudo code]

Answer (score 0):

But you already have the answer on the posted sheet!

To check for a string within another string, use the [InStr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) function:

```
If InStr(CStr(file), "PartOfFileName") <> 0 Then
  'file found, copy specific parts to that file
End If
```

[Here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-instr-function.html) are some more good examples on how to use the function.

It is advised to 'Dim' all your variables to have better control over your code.